# Cmake - Add all CUDA libraries

Tags: cuda, cmake

I am trying to add all the installed CUDA 8.0 libraries in my VS 2015 solution using CMAKE. However, with the current `CMakeLists.txt` file below, I only end up with `cudart_static.lib` and `OpenCL.lib` under my input libraries (Project properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies). Instead of manually adding libraries such as `cusparse`, `cusolver`, `cufft` etc., is there a way to include all the available libraries in the CUDA library folder, `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\lib\x64`, using a CMAKE command?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project( layerSeg )

# ==========================================================================
# find Boost 

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF) 
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)  
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF) 
find_package(Boost 1.63.0 REQUIRED filesystem regex) 


if(Boost_FOUND)
    message("Boost found")
    include_directories(${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR})         
    link_directories(${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR})
endif()


# ==========================================================================
# find CUDA
find_package( CUDA 8.0 EXACT REQUIRED)

if (CUDA_FOUND)
    message("CUDA found")
    SET(CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v8.0/include" ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    #include(FindCUDA)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
else()
    message("CUDA not found")
endif()

# ==========================================================================
# find openCV
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)


if (OpenCV_FOUND)
    message("OpenCV found")
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIR} )
    set(CUDA_USE_STATIC_CUDA_RUNTIME ON) 
else()
    message("OpenCV not found")
endif()

# ==========================================================================
# Find ITK.
find_package(ITK REQUIRED)


if (ITK_FOUND)
    message("ITK found")
    include(${ITK_USE_FILE})
else()  
    message("ITK not found")
endif()

# ==========================================================================
# find VTK

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
if (VTK_FOUND)
    message("VTK found")
    #message(${VTK_DIR})
    #message(${VTK_USE_FILE})
    include(${VTK_USE_FILE})
else()
    message("VTK not found")
endif()

# ==========================================================================
# ==========================================================================

add_executable( layerSeg main.cpp mainGPU.cu kernels.cu lsh.h lshGPU.h)

target_link_libraries( layerSeg ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} ${ITK_LIBRARIES} ${VTK_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to add all libraries in the `lib\x64` folder, one can add the append the following libraries to your `target_link_libraries`:

```
target_link_libraries( your_projectSolution_name ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} ${CUDA_CUFFT_LIBRARIES} ${CUDA_CUBLAS_LIBRARIES} ${CUDA_cupti_LIBRARY} ${CUDA_curand_LIBRARY} ${CUDA_cusparse_LIBRARY} ${CUDA_npp_LIBRARY} ${CUDA_nppc_LIBRARY} ${CUDA_nppi_LIBRARY} ${CUDA_npps_LIBRARY} ${CUDA_nvcuvenc_LIBRARY} ${CUDA_nvcuvid_LIBRARY})
```

Additional details regarding these CMAKE commands can be found at the [FindCUDA CMAKE docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindCUDA.html)

Comment: You could define a variable `$(CUDA_all_LIBRARIES}` and set it - and put that in a CMake module - so you don't have to repeat this super-long line in every project.